# How to set textbox.text pixels in blocks?

Tags: vb.net

I have a textbox named txtTotal, i want to set the result text in blocks pixels,

sth like this: http://bit.ly/1ack9Y2

Is there any way i can format textbox.text in blocks pixels and size 100 ?

I use VB.NET - Visual Studio

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a font, which looks like the blocky text - SmallFonts looks like that, I guess.

Comment: I searched but i couldn't find any font like the blocky text. I guess i have to sth special like a loop that chops the textbox text in pixels and then joins them, do u think thats possible?

Comment: @Milot25 Heres some:

http://www.dafont.com/llpixel.font
http://www.dafont.com/pixelate.font
http://www.dafont.com/pixelade.font

Your users however may require the fonts as well.